# Gridster jQuery plugin on AngularJS ng-repeat content going bad

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to integrate [Gridster](http://gridster.net/) with AngularJS, but without too much success yet.

Reading the documentation on Angular UI's `ui-jq` directive, I get the impression that [this (check fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Errfc/6/) should work. But when I look a bit further with Chrome's debugger, it turns out that on [this line](https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/blob/master/src/jquery.gridster.js#L87), it doesn't find any children at all.

I suspect that somewhere in the ng-repeat directive, AngularJS decides to rip out the part that will be repeated, and I see why, but that doesn't solve my problem. I'd welcome any clue that would help me to get a little further.

#### Update 1

I started turning it into a directive, hoping that would improve things. However, the nested `ng-repeat` is also getting in the way in case of a homegrown directive. I tried postponing hooking up the jQuery plugin as long as I could (`$evalAsync`) and alike, and eventually ended up using a `$timeout`. That's *the only* way in which I could get it working.

#### Update 2

I think the original approach would have never given me what I needed. So implemented a custom directive. See my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I eventually ended up writing my own directives for it. I needed to be sure that every change to the underlying data would be seen by gridster, but at the same time, I didn't want to write my own monitoring on the data model and replace everything you normally do within gridster with a directive that hides all of that. (It would involve implementing most of ng-repeat *within* the directive itself.)

This is what I have (and assume "foo" to be the name of my module):

```
foo.directive "gridster", () -> {
  restrict: "E"
  template: '<div class="gridster"><div ng-transclude/></div>'
  transclude: true
  replace: true
  controller: () ->
    gr = null
    return {
      init: (elem) ->
        ul = elem.find("ul")
        gr = ul.gridster().data('gridster')
        return
      addItem: (elm) ->
        gr.add_widget elm
        return
      removeItem: (elm) ->
        gr.remove_widget elm
        return
    }
  link: (scope, elem, attrs, controller) ->
    controller.init elem
}

foo.directive "gridsterItem", () -> {
  restrict: "A"
  require: "^gridster"
  link: (scope, elm, attrs, controller) ->
    controller.addItem elm
    elm.bind "$destroy", () ->
      controller.removeItem elm
      return
}
```

With this, I can have a gridster generated view, by adding this:

```
<gridster>
  <ul>
    <li ... ng-repeat="item in ..." gridster-item>
      <!-- Have something here for displaying that item. -->
      <!-- In my case, I'm switching here based on some item properties. -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</gridster>
```

Whenever items are added to or removed from the collection observed by the ng-repeat directive, they will be automatically added and removed from gridster controlled view.

**EDIT**

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7NWnuJftdZuGX5QUoXh7?p=info) demonstrating a slightly modified version of this directive:

```
angular.module('ngGridster', []);

angular.module('ngGridster').directive('gridster', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div class="gridster"><div ng-transclude/></div>',
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            controller: function () {
                gr = null;
                return {
                    init: function (elem, options) {
                        ul = $(elem);
                        gr = ul.gridster(angular.extend({
                          widget_selector: 'gridster-item'
                        }, options)).data('gridster');
                    },
                    addItem: function (elm)  {
                        gr.add_widget(elm);
                    },
                    removeItem: function (elm) {
                        gr.remove_widget(elm);
                    }
                };
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
              var options = scope.$eval(attrs.options);
              controller.init(elem, options);
            }
        };
    }
]);

angular.module('ngGridster').directive('gridsterItem', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            require: '^gridster',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, controller) {
                controller.addItem(elm);
                elm.bind('$destroy', function () {
                    controller.removeItem(elm);
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Wilfred, in the above example, where would one define any gridster.options if they wanted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer my own comment, you can override gridster.options in init like so: 

           gr = ul.gridster({
           widget_margins: [10, 10],
           widget_base_dimensions: [325, 325]
           }).data('gridster');

Comment: It doesn't work when you delete an item from items array, it also removes all the items after the deleted one (probably there's a conflict with ng repeat)

Answer (score 6):

If you want you can try and roll your own wrapper for gridster.  I spent most of the night last night and it was a little glitchy.  The way gridster handles serialization isn't straightforward, etc.  Anyway I stumbled on this project and it works really well.

https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster

I couldn't find an online demo so I made a plunk of it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/r5cSY1USjtr2bSs7rvlC?p=preview

Comment: Demo is now available [here](https://rawgit.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/index.html#/main)

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next release of

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/pull/347

The new deferred attribute will take care of the problem as soon as I can figure out why the stupid unit tests won't pass.

Comment: Ha! Cool. Do you happen to have a pointer to your version of `angular-ui.js` somewhere?

Comment: Not really, I'm still struggling to fix the damn unit tests so I can merge the stupid thing. Feel free to lend a hand: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/pull/379

Answer (score 0):

There's also [**Angular Gridster**](http://manifestwebdesign.github.io/angular-gridster/).

Came across it and this question while researching Gridster implementation in Angular.