# AngularJS with Gridster integration

Tags: angularjs, widget, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, gridster

I'm trying to join AngularJS and Gridster, I follow a code found here: [Gridster jQuery plugin on AngularJS ng-repeat content going bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394924/gridster-jquery-plugin-on-angularjs-ng-repeat-content-going-bad)

The problem is that when removing an widget (and persisting the data to $scope.items - in my case for cache use) after the first removal the content goes all wrong.

I click the next and it deletes two widgets (in the elm.$destroy callback). Can you help me understand how to save data on the fly without having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this, but you may want to investigate [angular-gridster](http://manifestwebdesign.github.io/angular-gridster/).